# Add line numbers to custom shaded environment in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have some paragraphs in a LaTeX document that I want to highlight with a custom shaded environment. The problem is that those paragraphs no longer get line numbers. How do I fix this?

Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{myshaded}{\colorlet{shadecolor}{red}\color{green}\begin{shaded}}{\end{shaded}}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph with line numbers.

\begin{myshaded}
This is a shaded paragraph, but no line numbers.
\end{myshaded}

Another normal paragraph with line numbers.

\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing pdflatex output]

## EDIT:

Following the comment by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, adding `\begin{internallinenumbers}...\end{internallinenumbers}` does help, but there is still a problem with misplacement of line numbers for shaded blocks spanning multiple pages. On my setup, the document below places the line numbers for the shaded region on the final page of the shaded region, undoubtedly due to line numbers being attached to the end of paragraphs, as the [`lineno` package manual states](https://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/lineno.pdf). I have not found a fix for this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{myshaded}{\colorlet{shadecolor}{red}\color{green}\begin{shaded}\begin{internallinenumbers}}{\end{internallinenumbers}\end{shaded}}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph with line numbers.

\begin{myshaded}

This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced. This is a shaded paragraph, but line numbers misplaced.

\end{myshaded}

Another normal paragraph with line numbers.

\end{document}
```

[image: Misplaced line numbers]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `internallinenumbers` environment to activate the line numbers for your shaded environment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{myshaded}{\colorlet{shadecolor}{red}\color{green}\begin{shaded}\begin{internallinenumbers}}{\end{internallinenumbers}\end{shaded}}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\tiny\color{black}}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph with line numbers.

\begin{myshaded}
This is a shaded paragraph, but no line numbers.
\end{myshaded}

Another normal paragraph with line numbers.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is definitely an improvement. One problem I have however is that if the shaded environment spans more than one page, the line numbers are all attached to the last page, i.e., the numbering is correct, but the numbers for the lines on previous pages appear on the last page of the shaded environment, but above the normal text and largely off the page. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @DavidKaplan Do you have a [mre]?

Comment: Try just adding lots of text into the shaded environment in my last example.